# Check if Cross Domain RSS has changed using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, rss

I have a website which loads a RSS news feed http://www.tagesschau.de/xml/rss2

I want to check every 60 seconds if the RSS feed has been updated. If it has changed it should reload the RSS feed. With Ajax I thought it would work great, though I am stuck here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ajax-cross-origin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkRSS() {
 $.ajax({
  crossOrigin: true,
  type: 'GET',
  proxy: "../php/proxy.php",
  url: "http://www.tagesschau.de/xml/rss2",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (xml) {
   //console.log(xml);
  },
  error: function(xml) {
   console.log(xml);
  }
 });
}
setInterval("checkRSS()", 60000);
</script>
```

(I commented the `success` event `console.log` to see if Ajax would trigger the `success` or `error` event. It triggered the `error` event.)

In the console I get `status: 200`, `readyState: 4` and `statusText: "success"`.

Does anybody know why the `error` event is triggered? I checked the url through http://jsonlint.com. It does load the list but gives me an error. Is this the problem?

Ajax-Cross-Origin plugin: http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/how.html#js-what-is-this-plugin

**EDIT**

I added a proxy php file from the [Ajax-Cross-Origin plugin](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/how.html#js-what-is-this-plugin) (and added its link in the Ajax code above):

```
<?php
$url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : false;
if(!$url) exit;

$referer = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) : false;
$is_allowed = $referer && strpos($referer, strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) !== false;

$string = ($is_allowed) ? utf8_encode(file_get_contents($url)) : 'You are not allowed to use this proxy!';
$json = json_encode($string);
$callback = (isset($_GET['callback'])) ? $_GET['callback'] : false;
if($callback){
    $jsonp = "$callback($json)";
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
    echo $jsonp;
    exit;
}
echo $json;
?>
```

Maybe a stupid question, but should I change `HTTP_REFERER` and `SERVER_NAME` into something?

What happens now is that the `success` event is triggered -YES!- but the outcome of its log contains nothing more then `" "`.

Comment: seems you are loading a plugin file. Does that plugin support what you are doing?

Comment: AJAX Cross Origin is a jQuery plugin to allow Cross Origin AJAX requests. This plugin use a combination of two Cross-Domain AJAX Request methods:
1. Use JSONP (JSON Padding)
2. Setting up a proxy

Comment: But it likely uses it's own ajax method instead of you just calling `$.ajax`. Provide link to docs. If it's the one I'm thinking of it uses YQL as proxy

Comment: http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/how.html#js-what-is-this-plugin

Comment: did you set up a proxy as per documents? There are other similar plugins that use YQL as proxy that don't require you to set up your own

Answer (score 0):

Cross Site Scripting policies will make this tricky... your best bet is probably to use a 3rd party API such as [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com) or Google Feed API.
The benefit of this is that *they* will handle the load from you and will still be able to retrieve updates from the original feed pretty quickly.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it, but first I'll try it myself till I pulled all my hair out. It is like making your own juicy hamburger and then somebody says; "there is a good burgerjoint just around the corner…" ;-)

Comment: Agreed :) It's always good have an idea yourself of the challenges so you can eventually see the benefit of "offloading" this!

Comment: Can you explain me your website Superfeedr? Because I don't understand anything…

Comment: You could host your own RSS proxy server, even on Heroku's free plan. Check out [RSS to API](https://github.com/csm123/rsstoapi) which you can deploy to Heroku or another PaaS very easily. (Disclaimer: I'm the author)